# Is it possible to get streaming URL using Youtube API v3?

Tags: youtube

I am trying to get Video URL from YouTube video ID.
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/2xJ1weLN7wc?v=2&alt=jsonc
This doesn't work any more.

https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=2xJ1weLN7wc&el=embedded&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US
When I use this API, I can't get video URL for WMG video.

How can i get video URL for all YouTube videos.
If anyone know about this,  Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?